# php code not running until second submit

Tags: php, forms

I had it working and at some point broke it yesterday and can't figure it out.

I am generating an html file from a form input.

I call a function if data is posted to the page, but the "foreach" loops don't run the first time the form is submitted...and it's 1 asset shy afterwards, if you upload 3 images, it'll show 2 on the generated page...

```
function AddClientDB($client, $pth, $project){
mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbname', 'pw'); //connect to db
mysql_select_db('tablename'); //select file
$indx = $project.".html"; 
$sql="INSERT INTO Clients VALUES (NULL,'$client', '$project', 'http://webpage.net/','$pth','$indx')";
mysql_query($sql) or DIE("Problems with the query:<pre>$sql</pre>" . mysql_error());
//Create client folder
    if (!file_exists('uploads/'.$client)) { 
        mkdir('uploads/'.$client, 0777, true);
        echo "Created Folder for Client: ". $_GET['client']. "<br />";
        }
//Make project folder under client
    if (!file_exists('uploads/'.$client. '/'. $project)) { 
        mkdir('uploads/'.$client.'/'.$project, 0777, true);
        }
$sql="INSERT INTO Projects VALUES (NULL,'$project', '$client',0,0,'$pth')";
mysql_query($sql) or DIE("Problems with the query:<pre>$sql</pre>" . mysql_error());

$myFile = 'uploads/'.$client.'/'.$project . '/' . $project.".html";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

//Top part of html page to make
$stringDataA = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://pixelfirereview.net/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    function popDate(){
        var dt=new Date();
        document.getElementById("dat").innerHTML=dt;
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="popDate();">
<div align="center">
  <table width="960" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
   <td><table width="960" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="480"></td>
      <td width="480"><a href="dbview.php" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.pixelfireinc.com/pfp2011/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/PixelfireLogoTopSM1.png" width="340" height="72" border="0" align="right" /></a></td>
    </tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>
     <table width="960" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
      <td><div align="center"</div></td></tr><tr>
        <td><div align="center">'; 


//Foreach valid file in the project folder, add it to our $content variable as a string.
//For some reason, the foreach loops only run the second time the form is submitted...if you hit f5 and continue through the warning about resubmitting data, it then fires the code in the foreach loops....


foreach (glob($pth. '*.jpg') as $filename2) {
            echo "<br />filename2: ". $filename2. "<br />";
          //  echo "<br />$filename size " . filesize($filename2) . "<br />";
            $content = $content . '<span class="m_title">'.$filename2.'</span><br /><p><img src="http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename2.'" /><br /><br /><a href="http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename2.'"><img src="http://pixelfire.net/clients/images/btn_download.png" width="235" height="50" border="0" align="right" /></a></p><br />';
        }
        foreach (glob($pth. '*.png') as $filename3) {
        echo "<br />filename3: ". $filename3."<br />";
            echo "<br />\n$filename size " . filesize($filename3) . "<br />";
            $content = $content . '<br /><span class="m_title"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Project Title" -->'.$filename3.'</span><img src="http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename3.'" />
            <br /><br /><p><a href="http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename3.'"><img src="http://pixelfire.net/clients/images/btn_download.png" width="235" height="50" border="0" align="right" /></a></p><br />';
        }
        foreach (glob($pth. '*.mp4') as $filename4) {
        echo "<br />filename4: ". $filename4."<br />";
           // echo "<br />\n$filename size " . filesize($filename4) . "<br />";
            $content= $content. '<br /><span class="m_title">'.$filename4.'</span><div id="mediaplayer'.$filename4.'"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pixelfire.net/clients/jwplayer.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">     
                jwplayer("mediaplayer'.$filename4.'").setup({
                    flashplayer: "http://www.pixelfire.net/clients/player.swf",
                    file: "http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename4.'",
                    width: "960",
                    height: "565",
                    autoplay: "false",
                    image: "http://www.pixelfire.net/clients/images/VideoPreview.jpg",
                    repeat: "always",
                    controlbar: "bottom",           
                });     
                    </script><br />
                    <p><a href="http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename4.'"><img src="http://pixelfire.net/clients/images/btn_download.png" width="235" height="50" border="0" align="right" /></a></p><br />';
        }
        foreach (glob($pth. '*.wav') as $filename5) {                   
            $content = $content . '<span class="m_title">'.$filename5.'</span><div id="mediaplayer'.$filename5.'"></div>  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pixelfire.net/clients/jwplayer.js"></script> <br /><script type="text/javascript">        
                jwplayer("mediaplayer'.$filename5.'").setup({
                    flashplayer: "http://www.pixelfire.net/clients/player.swf",
                    file: "http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename5.'",
                    width: "960",
                    height: "565",
                    autoplay: "false",
                    image: "http://www.pixelfire.net/clients/images/VideoPreview.jpg",
                    repeat: "always",
                    controlbar: "bottom",           
                });     
                    </script><br />
                    <p><a href="http://pixelfirereview.net/'.$filename5.'"><img src="http://pixelfire.net/clients/images/btn_download.png" width="235" height="50" border="0" align="right" /></a></p>';
        }


//Create the lower half of the html page

$stringDataB= '</div></td></tr><tr><td height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><table width="960" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>            
            <td width="620" valign="top"><table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><tr>
                  <td width="125" class="m_main"><div align="right">Last Modified:</div></td>
                 <td width="400"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>                         
                      <div id="dat"  style="margin-top:80px;background:#333333;padding:.5em;" align="left" class="m_main_alt"></div></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td><td width="350" valign="top">
              <table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"><tr>
                  <td></td>
                </tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td height="100"></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td>
                <div align="center" class="footer">&copy; 2013 PixelFire Productions<br />        (425) 917-1400      </div></td>    </tr>  </table></div></body></html>'; 


//Put the pieces together, top html, content, bottom html.
   $stringData = ''.$stringDataA . $content . $stringDataB.'';   
   fwrite($fh, $stringData);
}
```

It creates the HTML page and all, but the first time it runs $content is empty....if you press F5 after submitting the form and press Continue at the message about resubmitting data, it then runs the code in the foreach loops and $content will contain a string that's put in between the top and bottom halves of the html.......

Any ideas why that might be???

Comment: Mmmmm after looking that code I have a headache...

Comment: You have the code: `mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbname', 'pw'); mysql_select_db('tablename'); //select file` The second parameter of `mysql_connect()` should be the username and `mysql_select_db()` should be the name of the database.

Comment: ^ my mistake when I took out my real password/username table name, it's correct in the code... It seems the $content variable is only populated the second time it's run...can't figure it out...

Comment: alvaro how else would you do it? Need to create a Client folder, project folder within that, and an html page listing all the files in the project folders within each client....I hate php and hardly ever use it but have been tasked with it and it was working perfectly before I screwed it up trying to make minor tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by splitting it into a couple functions and forcing the order.